# Center-Align Images on Mobile Only

Tags: css, mobile

I have a WordPress site in which many of my images are aligned to the right or left. However, it doesn't look good on mobile.

Is there any custom CSS that I could use to center-align images on **mobile devices only**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You target mobile in CSS based on the display width, like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    // Mobile-specific CSS here
}
```

And then, depending on your code or theme, something like this for the actual CSS:

```
    img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```